# how to create circular progress bar like apple app installer in swift 3 or 4

Tags: ios, swift3, loading, swift4, progress

Is there any easy way to create circular progress indicator like apple app installer shows while installing new apps on iPhone?

I'm adding sample screenshot to help you understand.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use https://github.com/iwasrobbed/RPCircularProgress

```
lazy fileprivate var chartProgress: RPCircularProgress = {
        let progress = RPCircularProgress()
        progress.roundedCorners = false
        progress.thicknessRatio = 1
        return progress
    }()

chartProgress.updateProgress(0.8, animated: false, initialDelay: 1)
```